# .NET Best Practice or Framework Example: Function Overload vs. New Method?

Tags: .net, oop

**Disclaimer:** I do not wish this to become an opinion-based question. What I am looking for is *an example in the .NET Framework library* or  *a .NET best practice* that resolves my question.

I am currently designing a class and typically the caller only needs to send a single Foo, but on occasion the caller will need to send multiple Foos at once:

**Edit: There are other parameters as well as Foo and Foo[]. My apologies - I was trying to be generic.**

I currently have methods (separate methods):

```
int SendFoo(Foo foo, int timeout)

int SendFoos(Foo[] foos, int timeout)
```

But then I thought that perhaps I should go about it this way (function overload):

```
int SendFoo(Foo foo, int timeout)

int SendFoo(Foo[] foos, int timeout)
```

I'm leaning quite heavily toward the function overload solution as I believe I've seen this before, but I would like some proof that this is the correct decision.

I currently cannot recall of a similar example in the .NET Framework libraries or if there is an existing .NET Best Practice for this scenario.

Thank you for your time.

**Edit in response to using `params`:**

I cannot use `params` for the following reasons:

1. Sending multiple `Foo` objects requires special processing that I
   can not bypass.
2. I am using other arguments in the method that are not `Foo` type.

Comment: is it for some reason that you ruled out *param arrays*? that was made specifically for this

Comment: Actually yes, this is a wrapper around some native code. As `Foo` is a class (reference type) - when passing it as an array I convert the classes into struct equivalents (value types) for passing it into the native code as the native code is looking for a contiguous block of memory.

Comment: You could just send an array of 1 and only have 1 method.

Comment: @DerekW - I still don't get why you ruled out param arrays.

Comment: @Blam: But creating an array of 1 object for every call to this method when a majority of calls will be for only 1 seems undesirable.

Comment: @AlfredBr: See my edit: There are other parameters as well.

Comment: @DerekW - Since this is your wrapper, swap the order of the parameters i.e. public int SendFoo(int timeout, params Foo[] foo) { ... }

Comment: @DerekW - I think the reasons that you list as to why you cannot use params don't seem to apply in this case (or you did not describe them completely).

Comment: @AlfredBr: That's a possibility that I could explore as well. The only apprehension that I have is that it switches the order of the parameters. This wrapper has existed in other managed languages and I wanted to keep the parameter ordering consistent.

Comment: @AlfredBr: There's also the issue that processing multiple `Foo`s is different than a single `Foo`. I have stated that in the question and in various comments here.

Comment: @DerekW - If the processing is in fact different for one Foo vs. many Foos, then you should consider two differently named methods as mentioned in the answer you accepted.  That approach may decrease the ambiguity in your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examples of overloading:

- [String.Concat(arg0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khca9w90%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / [String.Concat(args)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9c94ey1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Array.CreateInstance(elementType, length)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb3cfh7k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / [Array.CreateInstance(elementType, lengths)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfs8044k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Examples of using differently named methods:

- [List.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / [List.AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [OpenXmlElement.AppendChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc846487%28v=office.14%29.aspx) / [OpenXmlElement.Append](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc846556%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
- [HashSet.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / [HashSet.IsSupersetOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346923%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Well it seems that even the Framework is a tad bit ambiguous on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this

public int SendFoo(int timeout, params Foo[] foo)
        {
            ...
        }

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer changing to use [IEnumerable< Foo >](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

```
int SendFoo(IEnumerable<Foo> foos, int timeout)
{
    // Work generically using foreach
    foreach(Foo foo in foos)
    {
        ///Processing of each Foo in collection
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple methods that do the same thing I would also call undesirable

You could do them all

int SendFoo(Foo[] foos, int timeout)  // does the real work

int SendFoo(Foo foo, int timeout) 
{
    return SendFoo(new Foo[1] { foo }, timeout);
}

int SendFoos(Foo[] foos, int timeout) 
{
    return SendFoo(foos, timeout);
}

Comment: You're correct, that would be undesirable. The calls result in the same thing. However, this class is a wrapper around some native code. P/Invoking an array of reference types does not translate well to the native code. So I translate these into value type equivalents before calling into the native code in the case of multiple.

Comment: Not following. What prevents you from translate in one working method? Do you process an array of 1 different than a single Foo?

Comment: Correct, I currently would in fact process an array of 1 Foo differently than a single Foo. Since the caller would be inspecting the contents of their array after the call had completed. I suppose, I could add logic to side step this in order to reduce unnecessary overhead or translating an array of class to struct when a caller has packed just a single Foo into an array. You've given a me a good idea. Thank you.

Comment: The issue lies in how .NET arrays are constructed. An array of Foo class will result in an array of references (essentially pointers), but the native Win32 code is expecting a block of memory, hence why I need array of Foo equivalent structs.

Comment: You are welcome.  And thanks for the +1.  And I still don't understand how a wrapper / struct cannot be handled in a single class.   But I don't need to know.